# Possible to retrieve actual raw URL for Rails request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request, uriencoding

I want to retrieve the **actual**, encoded URL value for a page I visit in my Rails application.

So, if I visit http://domain.com/dir/test%2Bpath, I should get the value "http://domain.com/dir/test%2Bpath" and NOT "http://domain.com/dir/test+path".

Is there ANY way to do this? I've inspected the Request object, Googled...nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In my system I can use `request.url` and `request.path`:

```
(rdb:1) request.url
"http://localhost:3000/test2/path/a%2Bb"
(rdb:1) request.path
"/test2/path/a%2Bb"
```

This should work in the controller or the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ruby helper method

```
URI.unescape('http://domain.com/dir/test%2Bpath')
```

Comment: I don't want to use any helpers; I want to retrieve the value directly from Request (or whatever) without any alteration from me, and I want that value to be encoded.